# Passing Java Generic Lambda Parameter Into Method Local Invocation

Tags: java, generics, lambda

Here, I am trying to pass lambda argument into local invocation of a method that accepts lambda argument:

```
package Desktop;

import java.util.function.*;

public class MyClass {

    public static <T, U> U myMethod(Function<T, U> myParam) {
        return otherMethod(myParam);
    }

    public static Long otherMethod(Function<String, Long> otherParam) {
        return otherParam.accept("900");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(myMethod(Long::valueOf));
    }
}
```

I browsed for some help on sites and it shows that we can pass lambda (with generics) from one parameter into another:

```
public static <T, G> List<G> fromArrayToList(T[] a, Function<T, G> mapperFunction) {
    return Arrays.stream(a).map(mapperFunction).collect(Collectors.toList());
}

/*
    Signature for map() is like this:
    <R> Stream<R> map(Function<? super T, ? extends R> mapper)
*/
```

Now how to properly pass a lambda with generics from parameter method into another?

Comment: The method name in `Function` is `apply()`, not `accept()`

Comment: @ernest_k still an error in compilation.

Comment: Yes, that's just part of the problem. The main problem is that you're calling a method that takes a `Function<String, Long>` from a method where the types corresponding to `<String, Long>` are generic. If `otherMethod` can only call `otherParam` with a `String`, then maybe `myMethod` should also be bound to `<String, Long>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem is that there are two signatures of `valueOf`. One takes a primitive long, the other takes a string.

There is no way for Java to know which one you mean.

You can manually specify by using a type witness:

```
System.out.println(MyClass.<String, Long>myMethod(Long::valueOf));
```

or, if you prefer, assign the method reference to a variable so that additional type information can be inferred from the variable.

```
Function<String, Long> func = FakeLong::valueOf;
System.out.println(MyClass.myMethod(func));
```

---

Another problem is here:

```
return otherMethod(myParam);
```

Fact is, `otherMethod` specifically requires a function that takes a String and returns a long, while `myParam` can be *any* function at all. There is a fundamental incompatibility here. Your design is wrong.

Comment: Bu why with fromArrayToList() method the generic lambda parameter works? Do you mind to again put down the complete version of a class like this MyClass but will compile+interpreted successfully? Im so lost,

Comment: @marcius.tan You haven't showed any sample usage, but that method has 2 parameters, so the type of `T` can be inferred from the array, meaning `String::valueOf` can be disambiguated

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code in this line `public static Long otherMethod(Function<String, Long> otherParam)`

You are calling non generic method form generic method, because of this eventually you have to cast your parameter which is not good thing to avoid exceptions while running your code

try below code

```
public static <T extends String, U extends Long> U myMethod(Function<T, U> myParam, T value) {
        return otherMethod(myParam, value);
    }

    public static <T, U> U otherMethod(Function<T, U> otherParam,T value) {
        return otherParam.apply(value);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(myMethod(Long::valueOf, "900"));
    }
```